# Using MySQL with WebStorm not working

Tags: mysql, node.js, macos, webstorm

I have a Mac computer. I have successfully installed MySQL. I know this because I am able to use mysql from the terminal. I even run queries and it works fine.

I am trying to learn Node.js with WebStorm. So in WebStorm I create my project, with `package.json`

```
{
  "dependencies":{
    "mysql":"~2.0.0"
  }
}
```

and then I run `npm install` which installs a mysql module. I run the following code, which keeps logging `undefined` for `results`. Any idea what’s missing?

```
'use strict';

var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host:'localhost',
    user:'root',
    password:'myPassword'
});

connection.query(
    'SELECT "foo" as first_field, "bar" as second_field',
    function(err,results,fields){
        console.log(results);
        connection.end();
    }
);
```

When I log for error, I get the following trace:

```
resutls is:: undefined
{ Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (/Users/mename/WebstormProjects/nodesql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:30:14)
    at Handshake.ErrorPacket (/Users/mename/WebstormProjects/nodesql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Handshake.js:67:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/Users/mename/WebstormProjects/nodesql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:197:24)
    at Parser.write (/Users/mename/WebstormProjects/nodesql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:62:12)
    at Protocol.write (/Users/mename/WebstormProjects/nodesql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:37:16)
    at Socket.ondata (_stream_readable.js:555:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/Users/mename/WebstormProjects/nodesql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:110:26)
    at Protocol.handshake (/Users/mename/WebstormProjects/nodesql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:42:41)
    at Connection.connect (/Users/mename/WebstormProjects/nodesql/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:81:18)
    at Connection._implyConnect (/Users/mename/WebstormProjects/nodesql/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:222:10)
    at Connection.query (/Users/mename/WebstormProjects/nodesql/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:137:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mename/WebstormProjects/nodesql/index.js:10:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
  code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
  errno: 1045,
  sqlState: '28000',
  fatal: true }
```

Comment: Also when I try `select user,host,password from mysql.user;` from the terminal, it says there is no `password` field

Comment: Error clearly states that user `root` is not allowed to connect here. It's quite possible that `root` user is restricted from login over TCP connection -- only socket or alike. It's all for security purposes. Therefore -- the best way to debug such case is to create ordinary user (e.g. `my_user`) and grant rights only to required DBs (or whatever restrictions you wish to apply here). Grant access from any host/IP for such user.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think your problem is related to WebStorm. It seems like your credentials to log into MySQL are wrong.

Have you tried to log into with your credentials using the command line? Is it working or is your login denied as well? Perhaps root login is disallowed.

Perhaps one of the following answers is helping you, if CLI login is possible:

https://superuser.com/questions/603026/mysql-how-to-fix-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost

Comment: lol. The very question states that I have no problem using the terminal at all. Perhaps you can help me with this. When I specify a port, say 8889,  I get `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8889`. This seems to mean that localhost is being converted to `127.0.0.1`. And now as troubleshooting I am trying to create the user in terminal and then run my code. But creating the user has no effect does not change the error in webstorm. I successfully create user as ` CREATE USER 'root'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword'`

Comment: Can you try to create your `root` user for all domains? Should be `CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'xxx'`. In addition, that specific account is perhaps missing rights to your database. So you could extend it to: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`

Comment: Thanks. I tried that. But access is still denied. Again no problem on terminal. But when I run the node js code, it does not work.

Comment: Two last ideas would be: use a different account than `root`. Perhaps you tried that already?
And you could also adjust your `bind-address` to accept all connections (also remote ones). But I don't think this would change anyhting as you are working locally.